# How to configure the robots.txt file with a multilingual site?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, url, robots.txt, multilingual

I have a site with Drupal 8 and I activate English and French (Language from the URL path prefix). Here is what my url resembles :

```
https://www.example.com/en/node/add

https://www.example.com/fr/node/add
```

And here is the current configuration of my `robots.txt` file :

```
# Paths (clean URLs)
Disallow: /admin/
Disallow: /comment/reply/
Disallow: /filter/tips
Disallow: /node/add/
Disallow: /search/
Disallow: /user/register/
Disallow: /user/password/
Disallow: /user/login/
Disallow: /user/logout/
```

How to configure the robots.txt file with a multilingual site ?

Do I have to add fr and praise each url or will it do it alone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Disallow` values need to start with the beginning of the URL path.

So `Disallow: /node/add` blocks `https://www.example.com/node/add`, but neither `https://www.example.com/en/node/add` nor
`https://www.example.com/fr/node/add`.

If you want to block all variants of the node add page, you have to use:

```
Disallow: /node/add
Disallow: /en/node/add
Disallow: /fr/node/add
```

(Note that I omitted the trailing slash. If the node add page doesn’t have the trailing slash, the `Disallow` value must omit it, too, otherwise it wouldn’t match. If the node add page does have the trailing slash, omitting it in the `Disallow` value is no problem, it will still match.)

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not clear. Are you trying to block any version of your site?

Robots.txt is used to disallow or allow search engines from crawling particular locations of your website.

Also, your current config is wrong, use the following:

```
# Paths (clean URLs)
User-agent: *
Disallow: /admin/
Disallow: /comment/reply/
Disallow: /filter/tips
Disallow: /node/add/
Disallow: /search/
Disallow: /user/register/
Disallow: /user/password/
Disallow: /user/login/
Disallow: /user/logout/

Sitemap: https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml
```

Also, you do not need to list out every single URL from a sub-directory. For example, if you want to block the SE to not crawl/index "user", you can use the below code:

```
# Paths (clean URLs)
User-agent: *
Disallow: /admin/
Disallow: /comment/reply/
Disallow: /filter/tips
Disallow: /node/add/
Disallow: /search/
Disallow: /user/

Sitemap: https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml
```

You can know more about how to use `robots.txt` using Search Console resources.

Comment: What I mean is that now in my url there is "fr" and "en" for the language of the site. Should I include this in my robots.txt file ?

Comment: If you are trying to block any URLs under "fr" and "en" versions of the site, then you can update it in the robots.txt file.

Example: You have example.com/user and example.com/fr/user, then you should use Disallow: /fr/user/ to block the whole sub-directory